# .Net core not able to generate token on server

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

My Class:

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { clientId+"/.default" });
```

on local accessToken  is having value and all works but on Azure server it returns Null.

I am getting below exception:

One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers'))System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers'))
---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers')
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.Throws.ArgumentNullException(String paramName)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AppServicesAuthenticationInformation.GetIdToken(IDictionary`2 headers) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AppServicesAuthenticationTokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(IEnumerable`1 scopes, String authenticationScheme, String tenantId, String userFlow, ClaimsPrincipal user, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Are you saying `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync()` returns `null`? I find that rather unlikely. Ate least its documentation doesn't say it can return `null`.

Comment: Might it be related to [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1801)?

Comment: No does not look like, in my case it works when running localhost but not on Azure

Comment: Updated with exception

Comment: could you pls let us know where you called `GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync`? the error message is pointing to this method. But what we have should be `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue in my side but everything working both in local side and in Azure web app. Could you pls take a look at what I have and comparing with yours?

You mentioned Startup.cs so I created a .net core 3.1 app and I also suggest you to upgrade to a newer version of .net as .net core 31 is end of support for microsoft.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
services.AddRazorPages();
```

In controller, inject `ITokenAcquisition` and have codes below:

```
var accessToken2 = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "client_id/.default" });
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://3743e7c8-ac84-4203-954d-78beed41b2d7/Tiny.Read" });
    ViewBag.token = accessToken;
    ViewBag.token2 = accessToken2;
    return View();
```

Here I want to say, when we are using `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` it should used for generating acccess token on behalf of the user, and when we want to generate access token for our own custom api permission, the format should be `api://client_id_exposing_api/permission_name` and I'm also confused that why we are able to generate an access token with `client_id/.default`.

The nuget packages:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.32" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.3" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "tenant_id",
  "TenantId": "tenant_id",
  "ClientId": "client_id",
  "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

Then I created an Azure web app in Auzre portal, we are not able to choose .net core 3.1 anymore so I chose .net 6 here.

[image]

Don't forget to add redirect url in the Azure ad authentication blade.

[image]

and here's my test result.

[image]

To troubleshoot your issue, I'm afraid you need to explain more about  `in my case it works when running localhost but not on Azure`, such as the exception messages if it throws exception, some logs if you added. You might enable application insights if needed.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your time here. I have matched everything here and is the same I am doing still the issue is there. The only difference is here i am using .net 5 instead 3.1.

Comment: I still recommend you to upgrade to at least .net 6 and have a try..

Comment: like you see I already proved my code could work... so, without any other error messages , we are not able to troubleshoot it..

Comment: Updated my post with exception.

Comment: Hi Just want to add here that my app is having Azure Authentication enabled and hence using Easy Auth. Hence i was not able to get token. If we disable the Authentication it generates token. But now i need to know how to get token from Easy Auth.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, and you might create a new question with details to look for help from Easy Auth experts I think